# opencv installation

Tags: ssh, software-installation, opencv

`I tried installing opencv on my raspi 3B using pip, on trying to import cv2 i am getting an error
[image: Attempt to install opencv on raspi 3B model with raspbian Buster]
**Edit:**
code lines:

Successfully installed opencv-python-4.1.1.26

`(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ workon cv
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python

> > > import cv2
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/**init**.py", l                                                                                        ine 3, in 
> > >           from .cv2 import *
> > >       ImportError: libQtGui.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or dire                                                                                        ctory`

**EDIT**
import cv2 is working
There was a library missing: sudo apt-install libQtGui4 worked for me

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. It's unreadable. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot access opencv in your virtualenv is because you have installed opencv in your system python environment. Each virtualenv keeps its packages separate from other vitualenvs and the system python. You can see the list of pacakges available from within each environment by `pip list`

To access opencv in your vitualenv:

```
workon cv
pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: i tried that as well, didnt help.

Comment: what is the output of `pip list` when you are in your virtual env?